# Jquery, Ajax, php, Datatable UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using DataTabels with PHP, AJAX, jQuery.

I get some data from MySQL database and when it contains some specific characters, then it crashes (characters like ä ü õ etc).

Here is where I "fetch data" to my table:

```
function fetch_data()
{
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
     "processing" : true,
     "serverSide" : true,
     "order" : [],
     "ajax" : {
       url:"fetch.php",
       type:"POST"
     }
   });
}
```

and this is my `fetch.php` where I make the output :

```
$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

I tried to add

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

To `fetch_data` function, but then my result just went empty... Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try adding `header("Content-Type: text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1");` to your `fetch.php` If it won't help try different charset ([Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5507/charset-issue))

Comment: would you please provide the code of get_all_data function?

Comment: can you please provide server side code also..?

Comment: read this **[informative q/a, right here on SO!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)** and review your solution.  A must read, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have MySQL query in `get_all_data` function, I suggest add `mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");` to your mysql connection .some thing like the following will resolved your poroblem

```
$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $database);
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
```

also you can try `json_encode( $output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` instead of `json_encode($output);`

Comment: God damn, i always forget "mysqli_set_charset" Thank you :)